# Exporting Excel Sheets as .txt files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to export sheets in an excel document as text files. Basically, I'm getting the output filepath from the user, skip the first sheet, and then save all of the remaining excel sheets as .txt files. I'm getting the following error when running: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or objected-defined error". This error seems to result from the ActiveSheet.SaveAs command.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub exportSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName, filePath As String

    'get filepath from user input 
    filePath = Range("E6").Value

    'ask if the user is sure about exporting 
    answer = MsgBox("Export all Worksheets to text files?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

    If answer = vbYes Then
        'loop through every sheet in the work book
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            'skip the first page in the excel workbook
            If ws.Index > 1 Then
                sheetName = ws.Name 'get the sheet name

                'save the active sheet
                ActiveSheet.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & "\" & sheetName & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I like this idea!

Comment: Not sure but help suggests `FileFormat:=xlText` is not a valid option.

Comment: And you always save the `Activesheet` instead of `ws`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for your code above

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String

    'get filepath from user input
    filePath = Range("E6").Value

    Dim answer As Variant

    'ask if the user is sure about exporting
    answer = MsgBox("Export all Worksheets to text files?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

    If answer = vbYes Then

        ' Turn off alerts. Be aware that will overwrite existing file without warning
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'loop through every sheet in the work book
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            With ws
                'skip the first page in the excel workbook
                If .Index > 1 Then
                    .SaveAs Filename:=filePath & "\" & .Name & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
                End If
            End With

        Next

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This cleans things up and seems to get me closer. However, it's only saving the information that's on the first page  (I guess the sheet that I have clicked on). How can I update the active sheet?

Comment: It saves every sheet but the first one as a text file! What do you mean with first page? And why do you think you need to update the active sheet?

Comment: Running the code you pasted didn't work. When saving the sheets, it was grabbing the information located on the first sheet, and only updating the name of the .txt file. I was able to fix this by adding "ws.Active" prior to the .SaveAs command. Although this may be a roundabout way of doing it, it'll work for my purposes.